# Jena Rule: How to use now(?x) Builtin primitive

Tags: jena, inference, jena-rules

Can please someone explain about now(?x) Builtin primitive in jena rule. I need to understand about this but not found resource on internet. Like example etc. 
Only found information about this from Apache jean website which is that:

**now(?x):Binds ?x to an xsd:dateTime value corresponding to the current time.**

**Any Example how to use in rules.**

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you want to see here? It's just a predicate which binds the current date time to the variable `?x` in the rule. You can use it for whatever you want. if you'd have another built-in to compute the difference, you could for example infer the age of a person, handle wrong dates which are in the future, I don't know. It's just there. you could also add your own custom built-ins, feel free to contribute

Answer (score 0):

call this function in rule body, here is an example :

```
[r1: (?s :startTime ?x) <- (?s a :Match), now(?x)]
```